# Mapas de calor cortados en Python

Tags: python, jupyter, gráficas

Tengo un problema con los mapas de calor (utilizados para representar correlaciones o matriz de confusión) devueltos por Python en Jupyter Notebook, y es que tanto el límite superior como inferior de los mismos sale cortado en la imagen, de manera que no puede distinguirse los números contenidos en cada caja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado volviendo a establecer los ajustes de matplotlib por defecto con

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
```

Incluso a reestablecer los de seaborn por sí fuese problema de ahí

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.reset_orig()
```

¿Alguna solución que se me escape? Dejo también el código con el que realicé dicho gráfico, aunque seguramente no este ahí el problema:

```py
plt.figure(figsize = (7, 5))
sns.heatmap(X.corr(), linewidths = 0.2,
            cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True),
            vmin = -1, vmax = 1, annot = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problema se debe a un **bug conocido de la versión 3.1.1 de Matplotlib**. Enlaces a reportes relacionados en el repositorio en GitHub de Matplotlib:

- [Fix inversion of 3d axis](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14579).
- [Heatmaps are being truncated when using with seaborn](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14675)

Es fácil de reproducir:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

corr = np.random.rand(5, 5)
plt.figure(figsize = (7, 5))
sns.heatmap(corr, linewidths = 0.2,
            cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True),
            vmin = -1, vmax = 1, annot = True)
plt.show()
```

En Matplotlib 3.1.0:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Matplotlib 3.1.1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema ya está corregido en la versión en desarrollo, tienes varias opciones:

- Te esperas a que salga Matplotlib 3.1.2 (poco práctico...)
- Usar la versión en desarrollo (con todo lo que implica usar una versión no estable) instalando desde las fuentes:

  - https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#installing-from-source
- Instalar la versión anterior, Matplotlib 3.1.0 que no tiene dicho bug:

  > pip install --force-reinstall matplotlib==3.1.0

Obviamente lo más sensato es esta última y esperar a que salga 3.1.2 para actualizar a no ser que casualmente necesites usar una característica específica de Matplotlib >= 3.1.1.